# facing issue while installing composer for zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

I'm trying to install zend framework 2 by using composer. I'm using xammp (windows server) for this.

1. First command `php composer.phar self-update` went successfully.
2. While executing `php composer.phar install`, I'm getting following error

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>    The "http://packagist.org/p/zendframework/skeleton-application$12d8b9f8d5d50b3186ca51caa64139beaf1a2f6c0720a4df288a169c250c09f9.json" file could not be downloaded (`<html>`)

I'm having `PHP Version 5.4.16` with enabled `open_ssl in php.ini` but still no success. 
When I tried

> "http://packagist.org/p/zendframework/skeleton-application$12d8b9f8d5d5
>         0b3186ca51caa64139beaf1a2f6c0720a4df288a169c250c09f9.json" by file_get_contents()

I got `404 error` , but by changing protocol to "https" I got response in json format.